# Can ASP.NET session use absolute expiration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

Can .NET sessions use an absolute expiration? From what I can find out, it seems to have sliding expiration. We are using .NET 4.5.2 and I ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.

We want the session to be cleared/abandoned/destroyed every 20 minutes, and not extend it when the user uses the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a value of when you want the session expired in a `Session_Start` handler. Then, in a `Application_AcquireRequestState`, check it there and `Abandon` the session.

I found this solution here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1175605/How-to-timeout-session-in-minutes-in-ASP-NET